# knockoutjs creating new model from input elements?

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js, click, submit

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Piercy/mD4kG/

So I have recently started working with knockout.js. I have started to get my head around it but am struggling with the following scenario.

I have the following model and view model structure:

```
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.Emails = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.AddEmail = function() {

                        // make ajax call here
                        self.Emails.push(new EmailModel(data));
            };
        }
        function EmailModel(data) {
            this.Id = data.Id;
            this.Name = data.Name;
            this.Subject = ko.observable(data.Subject);
            this.DisplayId = ko.observable(data.DisplayId);
        }
```

I want the ViewModel.Emails array to be an array of EmailModel's and my problem is how to create a new model to insert.

I imagine something like this:

```
            <select data-bind="options: Emaillistdata, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: DisplayId"></select><br /><br />
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"/><br />
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Subject"/><br />
            <button data-bind="click: AddEmail">Add Email</button>
```

However, doing this would mean the the Name,Subject and DisplayId bindings would need to be in the ViewModel (which they are not).  Also, it seems odd that I would have to add these to the ViewModel.  I am kind of expecting to able to click the button and have a data variable that i can just do data.Name, data.Subject and data.DisplayId and have these variables not bound to any model, they are just submitted because i've named them as such or something?  Then i can add them to the array and make them part of the ViewModel.

I could do all this with standard JS and then add it to the model but that also seems odd when everything else is using knockout.  However maybe this is the answer?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Piercy/mD4kG/

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to achieve from a UX point of view im not sure what your trying to achieve.

Have you looked at this ko tutorial.  It shows you how to structure your code to be able to add new items

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

Comment: i've created a jsFiddle, hoping it makes sense more now.  I think i should be doing something like the commented out version but cant figure how I am supposed to do it? http://jsfiddle.net/Piercy/mD4kG/

Comment: @Piercy Ive updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/h6VDB/2/.  Im not sure what you are trying to do is completely correct when using ko.  Im pretty new to it myself but what ive done works fine.  Just a note, you werent initialising your viewmodel correctly.  you want to initialise is like var vm = new viewModel();.  That way self = this; refers to the variable vm and not window.  Doing self.addemails without initialising correctly just pollutes the global namespace. There are plenty of explantions of this on the web.  Try this link https://www.google.co.uk/#q=this+is+javascript